# Can't connect to localhost when setting up canvas-sketch

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to learn canvas-sketch, but I can't set it up for the first time. After successfully creating a file, I can't open it because the connection to its server port (localhost:9966) is refused. It's not a firewall issue, but I have no idea how to make it work. Similar questions did not help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you trying to use the [`canvas-sketch`](https://github.com/mattdesl/canvas-sketch/blob/master/docs/installation.md) package?